# Looking for a children's book from the 1950s about an anthropomorphized animal who's abandoned by his family

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for a children's picture book that I read in the late 1950s about an animal (don't remember what kind of animal, possibly a mouse or hamster) who was a member of a large family. He came home from school one day to discover that his family had moved, apparently without realizing he was not with them. I remember that he wandered through the rooms of his house, emptied of all furniture and belongings. I don't remember anything after that! If anyone is familiar with this book, I would appreciate your letting me know.

Answer (score 4):

*Walter the Lazy Mouse* by Marjorie Flack

Description from [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24833504-walter-the-lazy-mouse):

> Walter is a lazy mouse. He is so lazy that he always misses school and
> spends all his time in bed. He is so lazy that eventually his family
> forgets about him and moves away…without him. Alone and scared, Walter
> heads out into the world to search for his family. He travels through
> a dark forest and soon meets a turtle and some frogs. Walter decides
> to create a new home on Mouse Island. His froggy friends live nearby,
> and Walter tries to teach them things. With his own island―and friends
> who depend on him―Walter must learn to take care of himself. There is
> no time to be lazy! But will Walter ever see his family again?

First published in 1937.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve been looking for this for many years and it just took two days to find it on this site. I’m looking forward to re-reading it and hope it won’t be as anxiety-producing this time around as it was when I was five!

Comment: You're welcome! Child's fears :) I still remember few of mine, so ridiculous now, but at the time...

Comment: @SusanWorley If this is the correct answer, you can mark it so, by clicking the ["Accept"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) checkmark next to the answer.